# Python - converting csv to a pickle causes 'write' attribute error

Tags: python, csv, pickle

I am working on a small sample python files. I have a csv file which needs to be converted to pickle. This is the code I have so far.

```
import csv
import pickle


class primaryDetails:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, contactDetails):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.contactDetails = contactDetails

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {}".format(self.name, self.age, self.gender, self.contactDetails)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.name, self.age, self.gender, self.contactDetails])

class contactDetails:
    def __init__(self, cellNum, phNum, Location):
        self.cellNum = cellNum 
        self.phNum = phNum
        self.Location = Location

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.cellNum, self.phNum, self.Location)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.cellNum, self.phNum, self.Location])


a_list = []

with open("t_file.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        a = contactDetails(row[3], row[4], row[5])
        a_list.append(primaryDetails(row[0], row[1], row[2] , a))

file = open('writepkl.pkl', 'wb')
# pickle.dump(a_list[0], primaryDetails)
pickle.dump(primaryDetails, a_list[0])
file.close()
```

**csv File**

```
Bat,45,M,123456789,98764,Gotham
Sup,46,M,290345720,098484,Krypton
Wwomen,30,F,758478574,029383,Themyscira
Flash,27,M,3646348348,839484,Central City
Hulk,50,M,52903852398,298392,Ohio
```

When i read the file and put it into a list I am not able to pickle the list. I also tried to pickle it using `a_list[0]` instead of the list, and it gives me the error  **pickle.dump(primaryDetails, a_list[0])
TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute**. I need to put the data in a list and pickle that so that I can save it to db [as mentioned here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html?highlight=pickle#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.pickle). Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed up the order of arguments to `pickle.dump()`

```
with open('writepkl.pkl', 'wb') as output_file:
    pickle.dump(a_list, output_file)
```

Documentation for pickle and all other standard library modules can be found at https://docs.python.org.

> **`pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)`**
>
> Write a pickled representation of obj to the open file object file.
>   This is equivalent to Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj).
>
> [...]
>
> The file argument must have a write() method that accepts a single
>   bytes argument. It can thus be an on-disk file opened for binary
>   writing, an io.BytesIO instance, or any other custom object that meets
>   this interface.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump

Answer (score 1):

Pickle.dump() requires a filestream object and the object you want to write to the file

```
file = open("file.pkl",'wb')
pickle.dump(a_list[0], file)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error saying `TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute`.

Comment: The order of arguments should be `pickle.dump(obj, file)`
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump